# My account is blocked from asking questions, and my questions are on hold

Tags: support, post-ban

I'm a new user. My Question was Answered but also put on Hold due being an unclear question.  Later my Account was Blocked. Since my question was answered, I replaced the question on Hold with new Question. Apparently this is a duplicate question that was answered.  So that answers my question but since my question is on Hold it can not be answered.

So how do I get my account taken off of Blocked status?

Comment: I've disassociated the question George mentioned. Please be more careful next time.

Answer (score 8):

Your account has been automatically banned from asking questions from the system because you have poorly received questions (questions with downvotes).

There are two ways to get your question ban removed:

1. Answer questions and get reputation
2. Improve your existing questions and hope people upvote them.

You [have a question that you shouldn't have asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018236/how-do-you-say-thank-you-to-the-folks-at-stackoverflow) and that contributed to you being question banned.

I've asked a CM to dissociate that post; that should lift your ban, *for now*. But beware, you're on thin ice -- take care to ask better questions.

Comment: Why fix it for him? It sounds like the question ban has done it's job correctly here.

Comment: My Account is blocked for ask question for 3 months, my Account is Active  this time And i get 100 reputation but my problem not solve and can not asking question!!i can haves hope for asking question???please help me???

Comment: Stack overflow :- Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. 
 
How to solve this problem. Please tell us